# "Unable to associated Elastic IP with cluster" in Eclipse Plugin Tutorial

Tags: eclipse, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am currently trying to evaluate AWS for my company and was trying to follow the tutorials on the web.
http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=2241

However I get the below error during startup of the server instance:

```
Unable to associated Elastic IP with cluster: Unable to detect that the Elastic IP was orrectly associated.

java.lang.Exception: Unable to detect that the Elastic IP was correctly associated
at com.amazonaws.ec2.cluster.Cluster.associateElasticIp(Cluster.java:802)
at com.amazonaws.ec2.cluster.Cluster.start(Cluster.java:311)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.wtp.ElasticClusterBehavior.launch(ElasticClusterBehavior.java:611)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.wtp.Ec2LaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(Ec2LaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:47)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:696)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl2(Server.java:3051)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl(Server.java:3001)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$StartJob.run(Server.java:300)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Then after a while, another error occur:
Unable to publish server configuration files: Unable to copy remote file after trying 4 timeslocal file: 'XXXXXXXX/XXX.zip'

```
Results from first attempt:
Unexpected exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
root cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

at com.amazonaws.eclipse.ec2.RemoteCommandUtils.copyRemoteFile(RemoteCommandUtils.java:128)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.wtp.tomcat.Ec2TomcatServer.publishServerConfiguration(Ec2TomcatServer.java:172)
at com.amazonaws.ec2.cluster.Cluster.publishServerConfiguration(Cluster.java:369)
at com.amazonaws.eclipse.wtp.ElasticClusterBehavior.publishServer(ElasticClusterBehavior.java:538)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:866)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:708)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:2731)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:278)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?
I followed the tutorials and the video tutorials on youtube exactly.

Best Regards
~Jeffrey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been resolved, it is due to the Elastic IP being assigned to the Server on creation.
Eclipse is unable to connect to the server if it is used.